# Running T4 templates from other T4 template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, t4

does anyone know if it's possible to run T4 template file from another T4 template, inside VS2010

Thank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is how I'm doing it:

```cs
string templateText = File.ReadAllText(Host.ResolvePath(templateFileName));
Engine engine = new Engine();
string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(templateText, Host);
//this is optional - record all output to your file of choice:
File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, output);
```

Comment: does this rely on T4 Toolbox?

Comment: For future reference: Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.11.0 and add <#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.11.0" #> and 
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #> to the T4 file.

Answer (score 3):

What your probably looking for is [T4 Toolbox](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox). It will allow you to actually generate code in individual files and add them to a project automatically.

Highly Recommended.

I have used t4 toolbox to generate whole projects just based on a model.

(T4 Toolbox was formerly located at http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/ but is now at https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox )

Answer (score 1):

We do this a lot. Here is an example how we reuse a common T4 template yet "pass parameters" into it:

```
<#
var currentUsername = "billclinton"; // this is for integration tests impersonating a user in our case
#>
<#@ include file="..\SomeTemplateThatIWantToReuseHere.tt" #>
```

And we keep our T4 template "generic" by dynamically determining the location that the T4 template is actually ran in (in this case, the T4 template that has the `include` line in it):

```
string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
var namespaceParts = namespaceName.Split('.');
var currentNamespaceLeg = namespaceParts.Last();
```

This allows us to do some very powerful templating without the need to duplicate our templates. The only thing being "duplicated" are our 4-line `.tt` files that have the `include` call in them, but these are pretty much maintenance free except whatever "configuration" we want to perform by passing in variables in the way we do it.