# T4 dynamic include directive

Tags: t4

I'm using T4 to generate some scripts as runtime templates. A part of this is to read some text files that include some T4 directive the for each file generate an output using a master template.

Each file may contain text such as:

```
Create table foo (
    rid bigint identity(<#= db.DefaultSeed #>, <#= db.DefaultIncrement #>),
    ...other table specific stuff
```

I have a template that includes the object data for the db referenced in the other files and some source file reference.

The main template to run could be like:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="Src" #>
```

Where src would refer to a variable passed to the template.
Then I would like to have a string list of files that could be iterated over to build individual scripts so that the following could be done in say a console program:

```
public void BuildTables(){
    List<string> files = getFiles();//just get a list of files in a folder to process
    foreach(var f in files){
        var mainTemplate = new MainTemplate(dbSettings);
        mainTemplate.Src = f;
        String text = mainTemplate.TransformText();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outPath + f, text);
    }
}
```

Howerver, it looks like the include directive is unable to accept variables like:

```
<#@ include file="<#= Src #>" #>
```

Is there a way to inject the text into the template file?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible. You could, however, process the content of the template entirely and make replacements on any part (the include also) but that involves implementing your own code generator (deriving from TemplatedCodeGenerator).

Comment: In the end I just using pre-runtime processing (I'm guessing like you are suggesting). The old files used a more Freemarker type syntax and I need to replace those markers for T4. This has the added advantage of allowing me to retain the Freemarker verstion and generating the T4 version

Comment: Partial solutions are to instantiate a precompiled template or the templating engine within the parent template.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636094/running-t4-templates-from-other-t4-template  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1529da89-5570-402e-b388-33a1966d48e9/dynamically-call-a-t4-template-from-within-another-t4-template?forum=vsx